# Did Arabs actually raise a red flag on the dome of their commander's marquee during the Haraam months?

Tags: war, arab

[This](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/10414/3487) answer to the question [*What is the purpose of putting a red flag on the dome of Hussain ibn Ali(as)'s shrine?*](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/10412/3487) states that if Arabs were at war with each other, during the Haraam months there would be a ceasefire (temporarily). To notify the opponent about it they would raise a red flag on the dome of their commander's marquee, and would resume thereafter.

Is that correct?

If so, how, when and why was this custom adopted?

Comment: Why doubt the existing narrative?

Answer (score -5):

Arabs before Islam raised the red flag on a tomb if the killer of the tomb owner had not been killed yet, and raised a black flag on the days when tomb owner was killed. This what Shia (Shiite) did until now on alhram months

Comment: Do you have any reference to back that up?